# Sorting efficiently by multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need to sort a large array (5 columns x ~500,000 rows) of string variables by two columns. I have code that works, but it takes an unacceptably long time, particularly because I have to do this on five sheets with different data.

I have been doing research, but the code I found tend to be for either a single column, or exclusively for integers. I need to be able to change it to work with between 3-8 columns in the array as well, but I'm hopeful I can figure that out myself.

- [Link 1](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-(sort-array-sorting-arrays)&p=2909260#post2909260)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)

Sorting on two columns:

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quantity Available").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quantity Available").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "C2:C" & LastRowAvail), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quantity Available").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2:E" & LastRowAvail), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quantity Available").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:F" & LastRowAvail)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
```

Sorting on one column:

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Tab").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Tab").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "U2:U" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Tab").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AU" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: FWIW IMHO worksheets weren't designed to work with that much data - that's the job of a database; I'm pretty sure at least one reviewer will suggest *treating your worksheets as a database* and have ADODB do the sorting instead of Excel. Personally I'd move the data out of Excel and into SQL Server; no worksheet can be nice to work with, with 2.5M rows of data to crunch; consider the actual use case this sort is trying to address: there's almost certainly a better solution that doesn't involve dealing with 5x 500K rows.

Comment: I think your question is fine here, *if you're looking for feedback on any/all aspects of the code, with particular attention to performance* - in which case it's probably better to [edit] the post and include the entire procedure, not just a snippet. ATM it's not clear how the two snippets relate to each other.

Comment: @Mat'sMug : We are in the process of getting a database program or R or some other program to handle this data more efficiently, but until then (2-3 month estimates from IT) I was asked to 'fix' the overflow error(s) the VBA is causing. I agree that Excel is simply not the right program for this, but I have no experience with SQL...

Comment: Overflow errors? Where is that mentioned? How is `LastRow` declared? Make sure it's a `Long` (32-bit integer). If your code is throwing errors, by CR standards it's not "working code".

Comment: @Mat'sMug : I don't want to post the code because it is really really terrible. I'm rewriting it entirely. The snippets are just two examples. I did previously ask for some help with the overflow error and posted the full code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156228/excel-vba-explanation-optimisation-needed

Comment: @Mat'sMug : I'm working my way through the code replacing the methods that were used by the previous person with loops. The sorts take a long time and I thought it was a stand alone problem I could ask about. The code shown does not reflect my proficiency and I am working on putting something together that is much nicer.

Comment: Oh but we **love** *really really terrible* code, so long as it works as intended ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug xD. I've found a lot of minor errors that are probably causing problems that the end users didn't even notice. (At least one place had the entire VLOOKUP transposed up by 7 rows.) Since it's not my code and the person on the last thread gave a lot of very useful advice I want to work through most of it on my own first. :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug LastRow is defined as Long in my new code, but before it was not defined at all.

Comment: Perhaps you're using Range().Count to get the cellcount, which may fail if there are more than a Long can hold. You should be using CountLarge instead.

Comment: Are you sure your "Sorting on two columns" example actually sorts on 2 columns? You have `Key:=Range("A2:A" & LastRowData)` which defines a 1-column (Col A) key, and you don't define a second key on a second column.

Comment: @FreeMan .... I copy pasted the wrong one. It's fixed now.

Comment: Can you answer this question and if so I may be able to provide 2 different methods. Is it acceptable for the data to be stored in a file and loaded to Excel / the worksheet to be rewritten with the rows in sort order.

Comment: @Raystafarian: You know.... I've used this sort set-up before in other projects, but this exact code might have been copy pasted from the record macro. I'm cleaning up someone else's old code and that would explain why they defined a few things oddly to me. I have written sort code of this kind before and just thought they were being extra careful by calling out more information then I typically do. These codes do work perfectly and I have written code very similar to this.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya : I can't think of why that would be a problem. I've never had an Excel code write to other files so there may be obstacles I'm not thinking of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm afraid it's going to be very difficult to review this code - it's sorting using excel's sorting tool. There isn't much to say about it without needing to re-invent the wheel, which may be what OP wants, but not what's presented here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My time became limited so here is the first and probably the preferable as it would facilitate migrating the data (lots of data) to a proper database.

Note I have mixed some StackExchange code and Microsoft code with my code (that was never intended for excel) to accomplish a form of data manipulation for you, as an example.

Please note you probably need to look at the connection string in "Public Function RecordSetFromSheet" specifically this part "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"

```
Option Explicit

' How to use as a memory file
'  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileName", adVarChar, 254
'  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileType", adVarChar, 254
'  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileDateTime", adDBTimeStamp
'
'  OpenData
'  DataSet.Sort = "FileDateTime DESC, FileType ASC, FileName ASC"

' Use Save / CreatePersistant / OpenPersistant as required

' Create a Recordset
Public DataSet As Object 'Facilitate Late Binding
Public MyFSO As New FileSystemObject
Private Sub Construct()

  Set DataSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") ' New ADODB.Recordset

  'See this link for datatypeenum "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum"

  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileName", adVarChar, 254
  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileType", adVarChar, 254
  DataSet.Fields.Append "FileDateTime", adDBTimeStamp

End Sub
Private Sub Destruct()

  Set DataSet = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub CloseData()

' Close the Recordset
  DataSet.Close

End Sub
Public Function FileExist(pFileName as string) as boolean

DIM RetValue as Boolean

  RetValue = False

  If MyFSO.FileExists(sFilename) Then
     RetValue = True
  End If

  FileExist = RetValue

End Function
Public Sub CreatePersistData(sFilename As String)

' Create the Recordset

  If FileExist(sFilename) = True Then
     MyFSO.DeleteFile sFilename
  End If

  DataSet.Save sFilename, adPersistADTG

End Sub
Public Sub OpenPersistData(sFilename As String)

' Open the Recordset

  If FileExist(sFilename) = True Then
     DataSet.Open sFilename, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdFile
     If DataSet.RecordCount > 0 Then
        DataSet.MoveFirst
     End If    
  End If

End Sub
Public Sub Save()

  DataSet.Save

End Sub
Public Sub DeleteAllRecords()

  While DataSet.RecordCount > 0
        DataSet.MoveFirst
        DataSet.Delete
  Wend    

End Sub
Public Sub Sort1

  DataSet.Sort = "FileDateTime DESC, FileType ASC, FileName ASC"

End Sub
Public Sub Sort2

  DataSet.Sort = "FileDateTime ASC, FileType ASC, FileName ASC"

End Sub
Public Sub Sort3

  DataSet.Sort = "FileType ASC, FileName ASC, FileDateTime DESC"

End Sub
Public Sub LoadWorkSheet(ws as string)

' See this Microsoft Document "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240(v=office.15).aspx"

  For iCols = 0 to DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 
      ws.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = DataSet.Fields(iCols).Name 
  Next 

  ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), _ 

  ws.Cells(1, DataSet.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

  ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset DataSet

End Sub
'
' See here for how to create initial file as in I have adapted it for consistency "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484516/vba-create-adodb-recordset-from-the-contents-of-a-spreadsheet"
'
Public Function RecordSetFromSheet(sheetName As String)

'Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnx As Object ' To facilitate late binding New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As Object ' To Facilitate Late binding New ADODB.Command

  Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") ' New ADODB.Connection
  set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") ' New ADODB.Command

  'setup the connection
  '[HD    R=Yes] means the Field names are in the first row
  With cnx
      .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
      .Open
  End With

  'setup the command
  Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "$]"

  DataSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  DataSet.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
  DataSet.LockType = adLockOptimistic
  'open the connection
  DataSet.Open cmd
  'disconnect the recordset
  Set DataSet.ActiveConnection = Nothing

  'cleanup
  If cmd.State = adStateOpen Then
     Set cmd = Nothing
  End If    

  If cnx.State = adStateOpen Then
     cnx.Close
  End if

  Set cnx = Nothing

  '"return" the recordset object
  Set RecordSetFromSheet = DataSet

End Function

' This plus the use of the DataSet.Sort = "String" examples may be all you need or want
' In addition this Answer may be all you need to persist vs the more generic I created
' Easiest would be to use rs.Save "filename" and rs.Open "filename" to serialize client-side recordsets to files.
' DataSet.Save "FileName" .... DataSet.Open "filename"

Public Sub Test()

'Dim rstData As ADODB.Recordset

  Set DataSet = RecordSetFromSheet("Sheet1")

  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset DataSet

End Sub

Public Sub Main

  Construct

  If FileExist("YourFileNameGoesHere") then
     OpenPersistData "YourFileNameGoesHere"
  Else
     CreatePersistData "YourFileNameGoesHere"
  End If    
'    
' These are for examples only and initial debuging / understanding uncomment one or build your own
'
'  Sort1
'
'  LoadWorkSheet "YourWorkSheetNameGoesHere"
'
'  Sort2
'
'  LoadWorkSheet "YourWorkSheetNameGoesHere"
'
'  Sort3
'
'  LoadWorkSheet "YourWorkSheetNameGoesHere"

  Destruct

End Sub
```